# THREE is not defined error

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I am trying to run some three.js examples locally on my machine. I know there are some problems with security so I need to set up a local server. So I'm running a local server with python. The background image and text displays but no animation is happening.

I checked console and getting the error THREE is not defined. I've downloaded three.js and put that folder in my project directory - any ideas on what's happening here?

The animation works in the browser when accessing from the `three.js` (examples) page. My script src is the same as the output of the command `pwd` when I am working on the command line in the `three.js-master` directory, as seen below:

```html
<script src="/home/iiiiiii/Desktop/test/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<script src="js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="js/loaders/PDBLoader.js"></script>
```

Comment: I guess your python server is not able to access files outside its working directory, hence the absolute path  to your desktop does not work... Can you show us your python server script ?

Comment: I'm new to python so I'm on the command line in my path where the files are 'test' dir and running python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000. I have also tried without a server, by opening 'index.html' in my browser - same output of background and text but no animation and same THREE not defined error

Comment: Check the `network` tab in chrome devtools. See if you're getting a 404 (file not found) on the three.js file. If you are, try symlinking the three.js file to the directory you've got all your stuff in and changing the file path appropriately.

Comment: yes I checked the network tab and sure enough it listed the files it couldn't find, so I had to manually change the path to these. But after doing this I got an XML error, so ran again from Python server, then got the original error messages. There are more dependencies than just three.js, it seems such as image (sprite) files etc.

Comment: If you're loading the html file with a file protocol instead of http protocol, that could maybe work. Most likely you're running it through localhost, so that file needs to be in your web path and the src path needs to be absolute (`http://localhost/js/three.js`), or relative (`/js/three.js`);

Comment: Or better yet, use a cdn source.

Answer (score 1):

Hi most common reason for this is that either you are not adding three js into your project as I can see in your given code snippet
`/home/iiiiiii/Desktop/test/build/three.js`
but given path is not a valid path to give inside a project I will suggest moving this file to the project folder like other js files you added in the given snippet.
Or Simply you can add a CDN for Three js in your project

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js" integrity="sha512-dLxUelApnYxpLt6K2iomGngnHO83iUvZytA3YjDUCjT0HDOHKXnVYdf3hU4JjM8uEhxf9nD1/ey98U3t2vZ0qQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `<script src="three.js"></script>` *EXACT* below the `<body>` tag that will help.

Answer (score -1):

Does this library need to be called at the top of your document or after the page has been rendered?
I notice you dont have a type set when linking your libraries. try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/home/iiiiiii/Desktop/test/build/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well I've copied the source code directly from the three.js examples. So it should work without this. However I did try and it hasn't solved the problem. The next step I'm going to try is to run it in an IDE (intellij) I'm really confused as to why this isn't working.

Comment: Can you console log window.THREE and see if it returns an object? @iiiiiii

Comment: The `type` attribute is completely unnecessary except perhaps in a few ancient browsers... not the kind of ones to be doing 3D WebGL graphics in.

Comment: @AlexFallenstedt shouldn't be the problem, none of the scripts are marked `async` and script loading blocks by default. Ten bucks says the problem is that the three.js file is 404ed.

Comment: OK so I have an update - I had to change the path manually for all files it couldn't find. Then I was getting a weird XML error, so read to set up the server again, so set up the Python server and now I'm getting file path errors again. So I've put this on hold for a while now.

Comment: there should be a more efficient solution than changing all paths within the script manually...this has something to do with project structure I'm sure and dependencies. Don't know how to deal with it.